# Annotation problema para mapeamento

Tags: java, jpa, annotation

Estou com erros devido ao meu mapeamento para o meu programa em java, ainda estou começando a mexer com annotation (peço que perdoem possíveis erros estúpidos xD).
O erro deve estar no @ManyToOne/OneToMany...

Possuo duas tabelas, CONTA e JOGADOR. Após criar uma conta, o usuario pode criar um ou mais jogadores, ou seja, uma conta pode ter vários jogadores, mas cada jogador pertence apenas a uma conta. Em meu BD eu criei uma chave estrangeira chamada ID_CONTA na tabela JOGADOR, para receber o ID da CONTA.

Alguém saberia me explicar como devo corrigir esse erro?

Erro:

> INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect nov
>   18, 2016 3:43:05 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl
>   useContextualLobCreation INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB
>   creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   Unable to build entity manager factory    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at Teste.main(Teste.java:10) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy
>   must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn:
>   Conta.jogador     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bind(CollectionBinder.java:478)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>     ... 3 more

Classe Conta:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Conta {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Jogador")
 @JoinColumn(name="idConta")
 private List <Jogador> jogador;

private String email;
private String senha;
private String nome;

    //gets e sets

}
```

Classe Jogador:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Jogador {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;
@JoinColumn(name="id_conta")
private int idConta;
private String nome;
private int lvl;
private int exp;
private int corrupcao;
private int ouro;
private int força;
@ManyToOne
private Conta conta;

  //gets e sets
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Guilherme, tudo bom? Tente dessa forma:

Classe Conta:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Conta {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jogador")
    private List <Jogador> jogador;

private String email;
private String senha;
private String nome;

    //gets e sets

}
```

Classe Jogador:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Jogador {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String nome;
private int lvl;
private int exp;
private int corrupcao;
private int ouro;
private int força;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_conta")
private Conta conta;

  //gets e sets
}
```

Aconselho você dar uma olhada neste material, para entender um pouco melhor o JPA.
http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/

Comment: Olá, vou dar uma olhada nesse material, mas a principio essas mudanças não funcionaram.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas modificações na minha classe Conta e agora esta funcionando corretamente.

```
@Entity
public class Conta {
   @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "conta")
     private List <Jogador> jogador;

    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private String nome;

    //gets e sets

}
```